# flutter my textfiled dropdown button options not selecting

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

[[image]][image: []1] here is my code for ..
i have two textfiled for selecting birth date and month....! and user is existing then value will shown automatically on textfiled ! and user can add new selected value from  dropdown selection....! in my case i can select items from dropdown but cant show selected items/value on tetxfild it is removing and textfiled showing blank ! plz help me on this......

```
  String _Dob;
  String _Anniversary;
  Future<UserUpdate> _futureDateeupdate;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  var month = [
  "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUEST", "SEPTEMBER", "OCTOBER", 
  "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER"];
   var date = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
   25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31];

  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
 _futureDateeupdate = DateUpadte();
  }

  void nextField({String value, FocusNode focusNode}) {
   if (value.isNotEmpty) {
    focusNode.requestFocus();
  }
  }

 FocusNode Anniversary;

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: (_isLoading)
      ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
      : FutureBuilder<UserUpdate>(
      future: _futureDateeupdate,
      // ignore: missing_return
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          TextEditingController _textEditingControllerDOBb = TextEditingController(
              text: snapshot.data.birthDate);
          TextEditingController _textEditingControllerDate = TextEditingController(
              text: snapshot.data.birthMonth);
          TextEditingController _textEditingControllerAnniversaryy = TextEditingController(
              text: snapshot.data.anniversaryDate);
          return Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[              
                Positioned(
                    top: 330,
                    left: 30,
                    right: 30,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 70,
                            width: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width / 2.6,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              onTap: () {
                                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
                                    new FocusNode());
                              },
                              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                                nextField(
                                    value: value, focusNode: Anniversary);
                              },
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                              controller: _textEditingControllerDOBb,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: const Color(0x3df58634)
                                    )
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0)
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Date Of Birth',
                                labelStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xfff58634)),
                                hintText: "Date Of Birth",
                                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xfff58634)),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: const Color(0x3df58634),
                                    )
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: PopupMenuButton<String>(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                  onSelected: (String value) {
                                    _textEditingControllerDOBb.text = value;
                                  },
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return month
                                        .map<PopupMenuItem<String>>((
                                        String value) {
                                      return new PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: new Text(value),
                                          value: value);
                                    }).toList();
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),

                              validator: (String value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'DOB is Missing';
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              onSaved: (String value) {
                                _Dob = value;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 70,
                            width: MediaQuery
                                .of(context)
                                .size
                                .width / 2.6,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              onTap: () {
                                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(
                                    new FocusNode());
                              },
                              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                                nextField(
                                    value: value, focusNode: Anniversary);
                              },
                              controller: _textEditingControllerDate,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        color: const Color(0x3df58634)
                                    )
                                ),
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0)
                                ),
                                labelText: 'Date Of Birth',
                                labelStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xfff58634)),
                                hintText: "Date Of Birth",
                                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                                    color: const Color(0xfff58634)),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        5.0),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: const Color(0x3df58634),
                                    )
                                ),
                                suffixIcon: PopupMenuButton<int>(
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                  onSelected: (int value) {
                                    _textEditingControllerDate.text =
                                    "$value";
                                  },
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    return date
                                        .map<PopupMenuItem<int>>((
                                        int value) {
                                      return new PopupMenuItem(
                                          child: new Text("$value"),
                                          value: value);
                                    }).toList();
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),

                              validator: (String value) {
                                if (value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'DOB is Missing';
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              onSaved: (String value) {
                                _Dob = value;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),


                        ]
                    )
                ),
```

Comment: Could you include an image/sketch of the design that you have in mind or are following? It'll help understand the issue better.

Comment: yes i uploed my image plz check